# Eclipse Plugin server refuses client connections

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am working on a eclipse plugin which creates a server on localhost and should accept client connections. Server is getting started successfully but it refuses the client connections. The same Server when I package as a Runnable external jar and launch as a separate process works fine and accepts client connections. I don't understand why it refuses when launched from within plugin system. Is there a security setting which I am unaware of? Please advice.

Code which works :

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("Resources-Module");
            URL chromeDriverURL = bundle.getEntry("/lib/java-io.server.jar");

            File javaServerJar = null;
            try {
                URL resolvedFileURL = FileLocator.toFileURL(chromeDriverURL);
                URI resolvedURI = new URI(resolvedFileURL.getProtocol(), resolvedFileURL.getPath(), null);
                javaServerJar = new File(resolvedURI);
                javaServerJar.setExecutable(true);
            } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            ProcessBuilder ps = new ProcessBuilder("java.exe", "-jar",
                    javaServerJar.getAbsolutePath());
            ps.redirectErrorStream(true);
            final Process pr = ps.start();
```

Code which does not work (refuses client connection):

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.setHostname("localhost");
        config.setPort(3700);
        final SocketIOServer server = new SocketIOServer(config);
        server.addConnectListener(new ConnectListener() {
            public void onConnect(SocketIOClient client) {
                System.out.println("onConnected");
                //This is never printed
            }
        });
        server.addDisconnectListener(new DisconnectListener() {
            public void onDisconnect(SocketIOClient client) {
                System.out.println("onDisconnected");
            }
        });
        server.addEventListener("send", Message.class, new DataListener<Message>() {

            public void onData(SocketIOClient client, Message data, AckRequest ackSender) throws Exception {

            }
        });
        System.out.println("Starting server...");
        server.start();
        System.out.println("Server started");
// This is printed
```

Server code taken from :

https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio/blob/master/src/main/java/com/corundumstudio/socketio/SocketIOServer.java

Comment: How are you running this in a plug-in?

Comment: In a dialog ..on click of a button and then run this in a separate thread